# C++ Quantlib output to console window

Tags: c++, io, quantlib

I am learning how to use quantlib to price derivatives. What is the best way to output some of the Quantlib specific classes to console window? For example

```
shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> forwardCurve(new InterpolatedDiscountCurve<LogLinear>(dates,discountFactor,Actual360())); 
Handle<YieldTermStructure> forwardingTermStructure(forwardCurve);
shared_ptr<IborIndex> euribor(new Euribor(3*Months,forwardingTermStructure));
```

What will be the best way for me to output forwardCurve to and euribor to console window? Then I can see the intermediate result of the code to see if they are as expected.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no predefined way to output those classes to console, but you can use their inspector to output the relevant data (so, e.g., you can call `forwardCurve->times()` and `forwardCurve->discounts()` to inspect the values you're interpolating) or you can call their methods to see the results of their calculations (e.g., `forwardCurve->discount(d)` to retrieve the discount factor at a given date, or `euribor->fixing(d)` to retrieve the expected index fixing). The returned values can be written to console.

As an alternative, you might consider stepping through the code inside a debugger. In modern IDEs, this will give you the same information more easily.